# Why is pre-processing causing me to lose dictionary keys?

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize, sentiment-analysis

Having a very peculiar problem. The `extract` function takes an XML file and produces a dict using restaurant reviews as keys. Here I am doing some basic preprocessing to the text as I'm using it for sentiment analysis: the text is tokenized, punctuation is removed and it is 'un-tokenized' before being reinserted into the dict.

```
import string
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize, RegexpTokenizer
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')

def preprocess(file):
    d = extract(file)
    for text in list(d.keys()):
        tokenized_text = tokenizer.tokenize(text)
        text2 = ''.join([" "+i if not i.startswith("'") and i not in string.punctuation else i for i in tokenized_text]).strip()
        d[text2] = d.pop(text) 
    return d
```

Of the 675 reviews, 2 are missing after this function has run. These are 'great service.' and 'Delicious'. I would expect these to be returned as they are, except the full stop should be taken away from the first.

For reference, the `extract` function:

```
from collections import OrderedDict, defaultdict
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def extract(file):

    tree = ET.parse(file)
    root = tree.getroot()

    if file == 'EN_REST_SB1_TEST.xml':
        d = OrderedDict()
        for sentence in root.findall('.//sentence'):
            opinion = sentence.findall('.//Opinion')
            if opinion == []:
                text = sentence.find('text').text
                d[text] = 0

        return d
```

If anybody is familiar with the SemEval ABSA tasks, you'll note I've done this in a somewhat roundabout way, not making use of the id tags in the XML but I'd prefer to stick to how I've done it.

Comment: You're using the reviews as keys, which means you'll lose any duplicates. Could it be that these *very* short reviews occurred twice?

Comment: Yes - that's it. Very obvious now I think of it. What would be the best alternative?

Comment: To fix your approach so that it matches your goals. I'd just collect them in a list, but I can't say for sure because I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, why you're using values as keys, or why you care that duplicates get lost. Maybe ask **a new question** that explains the task and asks for the right data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the reviews as keys, which means you'll lose any duplicates. Evidently these very short reviews occurred twice.

I can't think of any reason to use the reviews as keys, especially if you care about holding on to duplicates. So why not just collect them into a list?

```
d = []
...
d.append(text)
```

Comment: Have made use of the sentence id attribute in the XML to use as keys, which I ought to have done from the start. Thank you for your help!